# What is the difference between $\frac{x-y} {x} $ and $\frac x y$ $- 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I need to find the % difference between two numbers. One person told me to use $\frac{x-y} {x} $, another told me to use $\frac x y$ $- 1$ . Who is right?

Example:
Today's price:     $23892$
Yesterday's price: $23941$

Using $\frac{x-y} {x} $: $-0.21%.$
Using $\frac x y$ $- 1$ : $-0.20%$

It's almost the same result, but not quite. How to intuitively understand why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In don't understand your computations. Since $\frac xy$ is almost $1$, there is no way that $\frac xy-x=0.0021$. Actually, $\frac xy-x$ is approximately $-23\,891$. How did you get $0.0021$?

Comment: I had an error in the first formula: $\frac{x-y} {x} $ and $\frac x y$ $- 1$. 
Now they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *you get a different result when you compare $x$ to $y$ vs. when you compare $y$ to $x$*. Both results are valid and both of them tell you something about how different are $x$ and $y$ - but in a slightly different way.

Let's say $x=100, y=50$. Then, $y$ is smaller than $x$ by $50\%$, but $x$ is bigger than $y$ by whooping $100\%$ (and $\color{red}{75}$ is the number that is bigger than $y$ by $50\%$). You can see the same discrepancy, and for the intuition normally I would just remember this (or any similar) example.

The different formulae are, by the way:

$$\frac{x-y}{y}=\frac{x}{y}-1$$

to see how much bigger is $x$ compared to $y$, and:

$$\frac{x-y}{x}=1-\frac{y}{x}$$

to see how much smaller is $y$ compared to $x$.

Comment: Thanks. This is also a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is the first value and $y$ the second one, you should use
$$\frac{y-x}{x}$$

In you example:
$$x=23941$$
$$y=23892$$
Percentual variation:
$$\frac{23882-23941}{23941}=\frac{-59}{23941}=-0.00246439163 \cong -0.246\%$$

Comment: 23892, not 23882.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, 23892 not 23882. Thanks GEdgar

Answer (score 1):

The percent difference can be found by using the equation $$\dfrac {x - y}{y}\cdot 100\%$$ where $x$ is the new value and $y$ is the old value.  Simplifying the fraction above gives us $$\bigg(\dfrac {x}{y} - 1\bigg) \cdot 100\%$$ so the second equation is the appropriate one to use.

To wit, $$\dfrac {23892 - 23941}{23941}\cdot 100\% = -\dfrac {49}{23941}\cdot 100\% = -0.00204 \cdot 100\% = -0.204\%.$$

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the explanation.